# How to calculate mean with backward time windows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Not sure if i have put correct title for my question, please suggest edit

I have the following dataframe :

```
df_dict={'startDate': 
['2015-01-01','2015-01-05','2015-01-18','2015-01-25',
'2015-02-02','2015-02-03','2015-02-04','2015-02-17',
'2015-03-03','2015-03-04','2015-03-07','2015-03-11',
'2015-04-04','2015-04-05','2015-04-17','2015-04-19'],
'price':[200,250,270,240,100,120,130,140,300,310,330,370,400,410,420,440],

'250_index': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

i need to find the first available date in my dataset which in this case is `2015-01-01` then create `30day` intervals, for example: `2015-01-01` ,`2015-01-31`,`2015-03-02`,`2015-04-01` then for each interval and `250_index` combination calculates past `30day` `60_day` and `90day` average price.

resulting dataframe should be something like following, past averages for first interval is `0` as we have no information about what happened, but for second interval `2015-01-31` we need to calculate `past_30_avg` based on prices we have between `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-31`, same for other intervals:

```
time_interval    index    past_30_avg  past_60_avg  past_90_avg
 '2015-01-01'     1         0             0            0
                  2         0             0            0
 '2015-01-31'     1         235           0            0
                  2         245           0            0
 '2015-03-02'     1         115          175           0
                  2         130          187           0
 '2015-04-01'     1         315          240          221    
                  2         340          235          238
```

i was looking for a generalized approach as it is just a portion of my datset

Comment: @ MaxU Appreciate your help.

Comment: @chrisaycock i'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`pd.Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) for the 30 days means (monthly aggregation) and then [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) with [`rolling()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for 60 and 90 days:

```
tdf = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='startDate', freq='30D', label='right'), '250_index']).mean()\
              .reset_index().rename(columns={'price': 'past_30_avg'})
print(tdf)

tdf['past_60_avg'] = tdf.groupby('250_index')['past_30_avg'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean())
tdf['past_90_avg'] = tdf.groupby('250_index')['past_30_avg'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean())

#    startDate  250_index  past_30_avg  past_60_avg  past_90_avg
# 0 2015-01-31          1          235          NaN          NaN
# 1 2015-01-31          2          245          NaN          NaN
# 2 2015-03-02          1          115        175.0          NaN
# 3 2015-03-02          2          130        187.5          NaN
# 4 2015-04-01          1          315        215.0   221.666667
# 5 2015-04-01          2          340        235.0   238.333333
# 6 2015-05-01          1          410        362.5   280.000000
# 7 2015-05-01          2          425        382.5   298.333333
```